# Select a specific number of records from a record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Query that is working normally but now I need to show only 4 record from record 5 of the database?

How would this query look?

```
Select   noticias.id,
         idn,
         titulo,
         chamada,
         foto_a,
         subcatid,
         noticias_subcategorias.subcategoria,
         slug,
         noticias.rlogdata
From     noticias,
         noticias_subcategorias
Where    noticias.subcatid = noticias_subcategorias.id
         And noticias.status = 1
         And posicao = 1
         And noticias.tipo = 2
Order By idn Desc
Limit 0, 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include a snapshot(no screenshots pls) of both table noticias and noticias_subcategorias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start at record 5, you'd use LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4 to skip the first 4 records.

Comment: And how would that look? I've never done a query like this, can you help me?

Comment: I obtained this way: LIMIT 5,4. Thanks!